# Qt vs GTK+ performance

Tags: performance, qt, gtk

Is there anybody compared the performance of Qt apps and Gtk+ apps in different platforms? e.g.:create the same layout windows or paint the same 2D/3D graphics with 1000 times.

Comment: I've used Qt and it's not slow at all. And when you're dealing with graphics those kinds of delays aren't noticable to the user anyway. If fact, I'd say Qt feels smoother because they always use caching so your app will never flicker.

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard benchmark for speed, as both libraries do things in different ways. Each library has its strengths and weaknesses in terms of performance (Does GTK have a graphicsview type api?)